# Using "this" as an argument to a constructor

Tags: android, constructor, this

I am working through the tutorials provided by Google for learning how to make Android apps and I don't understand why they pass this as an argument when creating and instance of TextView. Here is the code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this); //The line in question, why do they use "new TextView(this)
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);
    setContentView(textView);
```

Comment: You need to tell your textView that it is associated with your view (this)

Answer (score 2):

You should read the Java documentation first since much of Android development requires a strong understanding of the language basics. [This link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) explains the use of `this`.

`this` is a reference to the current instance of the class which `onCreate` belongs to. In this case, it refers to the `Activity` instance.

The [`TextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#TextView%28android.content.Context%29) constructor takes a `Context` object as parameter, and the `Activity` class itself extends `Context`.

This way the method `onCreate` creates a `TextView` that belongs to *this* activity.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) the constructor requires a variable of type Context.  The TextView needs this so it can understand what's currently going on with the program.

Answer (score 0):

"This" is the reference of the current object, hence the look at the class which holds the method.

Answer (score 0):

The [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) class has many constructors and one of them accepts a parameter of type [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html).

The `this` keyword refers to the current object, So the object is a type of Context.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `TextView` shows that when you want to call the 1-argument constructor you must pass a reference to a `Context` object. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#TextView%28android.content.Context%29).

What you're doing by using `this` is passing a reference to the current instance of the class to the constructor. In the case of your code you'd be calling it from an `Activity` which is a child of the `Context` class. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)